# strange namespaces declarations

Tags: xml-namespaces, jena

I'm using jena 2.6.4, and I notice a strange behavior with namespaces. I'm using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myUri = "http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#";
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);

    model.setNsPrefix("myuri", myUri);

    OntClass c616 = model.createClass(myUri + "616");
    OntClass c123 = model.createClass(myUri + "123");

    Individual a = c616.createIndividual(myUri + "a");
    a.addOntClass(c123);

    model.write(System.out);
}
```

The output is:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#616"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:j.1="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#123"
    xmlns:myuri="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#123">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#a">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#123"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#616"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#616">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I don't understand why the following namespaces are declared:

```
xmlns:j.0="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#616"
xmlns:j.1="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#123"
```

Strangely, If I change the serialization to TURTLE (`model.write(System.out, "TURTLE");`), then I get the following output:

```
@prefix myuri:   <http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#123>
      a       owl:Class .

myuri:a
      a       <http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#123> , <http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#616> .

<http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#616>
      a       owl:Class .
```

Where namespaces declarations are as I expected.

I've also noticed I different behavior when changing `OntClass` names from `616` to `c616` and `123` to `c123`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myUri = "http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#";
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);

    model.setNsPrefix("myuri", myUri);

    OntClass c616 = model.createClass(myUri + "c616");
    OntClass c123 = model.createClass(myUri + "c123");

    Individual a = c616.createIndividual(myUri + "a");
    a.addOntClass(c123);

    model.write(System.out);
}
```

outputs:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:myuri="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#c123">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#a">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#c123"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#c616"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#c616">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and in TURTLE format:

```
@prefix myuri:   <http://www.example.com/1.0/myUri#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

myuri:c123
      a       owl:Class .

myuri:a
      a       myuri:c123 , myuri:c616 .

myuri:c616
      a       owl:Class .
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone explain this strange behavior?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two prefixes are not used and do not affect the 'nature' of your RDF graph.
The so called 'localnames' cannot start with a number, see:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar

The two prefixes in your first example (j.0 and j.1) are not actually used, why they concern you so much?

Comment: I didn't know that localnames could not start with a number: thank you for the links! My concern was related to (i) understanding why such namespaces are added by jena if they are not used, and (ii) why they appear only in the RDF/XML serialization. Anyway, I think my take-away lesson is that I must not use localnames starting with numbers :)