# Correcting the namespace of vocabularies

Tags: jena

Given this (very contrived) code snippet:

```
System.out.println(VCARD.uri);
System.out.println(SKOS.uri);

Resource johnSmith  = model.createResource("http://somewhere/js")
        .addProperty(VCARD.FN, "John Smith")
        .addProperty(SKOS.notation, "John Smith");

model.write(System.out);
```

we get

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#
http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#

<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/js">
    <j.0:notation>John Smith</j.0:notation>
    <vcard:FN>John Smith</vcard:FN>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Given that `SKOS` is represented internally in Jena, why is it still returning the `j.0` notation (yet not for the `vcard` property)? I've read similar questions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735008/strange-namespaces-declarations) and [this one](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201108.mbox/%3CCABPWEL_5Efk7u0MfgQ+E1vwFRQw_6CgRAnxNbv07A3eVpsHSjg@mail.gmail.com%3E) and [this one](http://nuin.blogspot.co.uk/2005/04/jena-tip-namespaces-and-j0-problem.html)) but they seem to refer to people referring to their own ontology. Given that the `uri` constant is correct for `SKOS`, why does it change in the RDF representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has used URIs from SKOS but not set the prefix on the model.  See `setNsPrefix`.

You may wish to use the pretty printing form of output, the default is only basic RDF/XML.  Set the syntax name in the `model.write` call (see javadoc for details).

Comment: I couldn't see anywhere in the documentation which says which `vocabularies` have the ns set internally in Jena (obviously `vcard` does, but `skos` doesn't) - does a list exist?